# Modeling of multiple user's time series data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series

I have a dataset where I have multiple users, and for each user I have time series data. Let's say the problem is similar to people buying cars. I have some personal data, and then a time series of events, like User A is 56 years old, looked at a car at 5am, then used the configurator at 7pm, then bought the car the next day. Then User B is 40 years old, looked at the car, then didn't use the configurator, then didn't buy the car. And I have thousands of these.

What I'm trying to do is to develop a model that can predict a user's next step. I've looked at [some tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series), but these usually only have a single time series that they train and predict on.

So the usual tutorial data setup is:

```
time  event
9:30  1
9:45  2
10:00 3 
...
```

Mine is:

```
user time  event affects_stuff amount
1    9:45  1     0             100
2    9:45  7     1             200
1    10:00 5     0             300
3    11:00 1     0             100
```

The question is, how can I use a time series model to train and then predict on multiple users, as described in the example? Do I just transform the data so that each user has one time series to their name, and feed it individually to an LSTM for example? Or do I have to train a model for each user (this doesn't seem right, since the model should learn a type of behavior and generalize it to other users with similar data)? Or how do I start modeling something like this? What models can be used for such a problem? If I understand correctly, this issue is not just a multivariate problem, but also multi-input so to say, vs. the TF example above (which also contains code for multivariate option, but only on a single time series).

The goal would be the usual, predict the next step in the time series for a specific user, but I'd like the model to learn from what other users usually do, too.